# MVC4 Entity Framework not rebuilding classes

Tags: entity, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a new MVC4 application. Whenever I add/change my SQL Server database and the run the Update Model From Database option in the EDMX designer it appears to work (I can see Field additions and new Stored Procedures) However, the changes are not avaialable in my code. I have to delete the EDMX file and start over, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can right click and choose run custom tool. This will re run the t4 Templates to and regenerate the code. You might have to do this once on each TT file under the edmx file.